# How can I access the gradients for every example in a minibatch?

Tags: keras, theano

I'm writing an optimizer for Keras and would like the update on some parameter to depend on the statistics of the gradient *within* the minibatch. So, I need some way to access the gradients for each example in the minibatch.

Is there a graceful way to do this in, for example, Theano? I don't see how, now. `theano.gradients.grad` takes a full minibatch tensor as input/output, but there's no clear way to access each gradient individually without wholly redefining all the ops and `grad`.

Or, is there a not-graceful way to do this in Keras? I could call `keras.model.train_on_batch` from within my optimizer's `get_gradients`, but this would require that I have access to the input data from within the optimizer. Currently this is not the case; inputs are not an attribute of `model` and aren't accessible. So a proxy question would be **how can I access the minibatch inputs/outputs from within an optimizer?**

The not-graceful way can be super inefficient, for the moment. It's more important that I figure out if this optimization algorithm would actually work.